# Return XML List from WCF REST Service

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Rest service and I am currently returning a list of type "Book".  The service works fine, the information returned is not in xml format.  This makes it impossible to parse, how do I get it to show up in xml format.

OR can I parse by using the class type in the client?

Thanks for any help

**The Service**

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ListAllBooks", 
            ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    List<Book> ListAllBooks()
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        Book aBook;
        String query = "SELECT ID, ISBN, Title, Author, Genre, Format, Inventory, Price FROM books";
        SqlDataReader reader = queryDB(query, connectionString);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            aBook = new Book();
            aBook.Author = reader["Author"].ToString();
            aBook.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
            aBook.ID = reader["ID"].ToString();
            aBook.Inventory = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Inventory"]);
            aBook.ISBN = reader["ISBN"].ToString();
            aBook.Price = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Price"]);
            aBook.Genre = reader["Genre"].ToString();
            aBook.Format = reader["Format"].ToString();
            bookList.Add(aBook);
        }
        return bookList;
    }
```

**The Type Book**

```
    public class Book
    {
        public String ID { get; set; }
        public String ISBN { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Author { get; set; }
        public String Genre { get; set; }
        public String Format { get; set; }
        public int Inventory { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the format? Is it JSON? Why your code does not work? I am expecting it to work.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://login.scottsmereka.com/ListAllBooks

Comment: This is valid pure XML! What's wrong with it?

Comment: Hmm really?  I was expecting tags <ID>12345</ID>.  How would I go about parsing this information in my client?

Comment: Well ID seems to be a GUID. But XML is both valid and well-formed.

Comment: Stop using a web browser as a debugging tool.  Go download fiddler and use that.  What you are getting back is plain old XML.

Comment: @Scott: you need to **View Source** on that page output! It **IS** XML - in all its glory - your browser just probably parses out all XML tags and stuff....